# Word for a person who doesn’t let anyone get in their way?

Tags: single-word-requests, british-english

I have to write about Miss Trunchbull in English, and Dahl states ‘she ploughed on like a tank, with small people bouncing off her to left and right.’ So I thought she doesn’t let anyone get in her way? But when I searched it, it came up with strong minded, and I don’t want her to sound like a good person.

Comment: Hi Katie. As the (determined) answer below shows, the phrase "doesn’t let anyone get in their way" has two interpretations: the (very common) figurative and the literal. If you leave your question as it is, you’re going to get lots of answers for the figurative (strong minded, determined etc) but I think you want the literal (unstoppable force, physically strong, ploughing through crowds with cheerful disregard of other people). You can edit to clarify, and maybe add a link to Matilda - not everyone has read it.

Comment: "Strong minded" does not automatically have a 'good' or positive implication. Hitler, one imagines, was strong-minded.

Comment: Is [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZIUFf6nQIA) what you are referring to ?

Comment: Looking up synonyms for 'strong minded' gives _determined, committed, unswerving, unwavering, resolute, purposeful, devoted, dedicated, uncompromising, tireless, tenacious, persistent, indefatigable, dogged,  peremptory, pertinacious, mulish, obdurate_ and others; haven't you considered these?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Strong-willed (willful) is more like it.

Answer (score 1):

A determined person would never let anyone get in their way.. I think the word you're looking for is """determined""

Answer (score 0):

I would call Miss Trunchbull **"Tyrannical"**

> https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tyrannical
>
> "Exercising power in a cruel or arbitrary way.
>   ‘a tyrannical government’ dictatorial, despotic, autocratic, oppressive, repressive, fascistic, tyrannous, absolute, totalitarian, arbitrary, undemocratic, anti-democratic, illiberal"

Answer (score 0):

**mulish**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/mulish)

> adj.
>   1. Extremely or irrationally stubborn and intractable

Answer (score 0):

She is a [**Juggernaut**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/juggernaut):

> A huge, powerful, and overwhelming force.
>
> ‘But the reality is that the juggernaut just keeps rolling on and on.’
> ‘He described the development, which could start as early as 2007, as ‘a huge juggernaut heading this way’.’
> ‘Tan explores growing unease about the power of brands and of corporate juggernauts.’